# Can you use map function within a class React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to map through the database and return certain variables. I want to be able to do this within a class if possible.
I have fetched from my database like this:

```
class MyDevices extends Component {

state = {
    house: [],
    selectedMovie: null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.herokuapp.com/dwelling/house/', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        //'Authorization': 'Token'
      }
    }).then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(resp => this.setState({ house: resp }))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }

  houseClicked = h => {
    console.log(h)
  }
  ...
}
```

I have later passed it into functions which are in a different js component like: `<DeviceCard house={this.state.house} houseClicked={this.h}></DeviceCard>`
Then within the DeviceCard function I use:

```
function DeviceCard(props) {

    return (

        <div>
            {props.house.map(house => {

                const code = house.dwelling_code;
                const state = house.room[0].devices[0].state;
            ...})}
        </div>
    );
}
```

However, I am wondering whether it is possible to get data from my database in the class instead of passing it to a new function. I am new to React so this may be very simple but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you want to show data in a different component you have to pass it like you're doing now. What is the issue?

Comment: you already get data in `componentDidMount` you might use `house.data.map(/*render child component here*/)` as well

Answer (score 1):

Consider using render method:

```
class MyDevices extends Component {
...
render() {
    return house.map(item => {
                const code = item.dwelling_code;
                const state = item.room[0].devices[0].state;
       })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I understand you correctly, you want { MyDevices } father component do the logic of mapping through results, and { DeviceCard } child component will be so-called "pure component", and will contain only HTML code for each device card it get -

---

```
     class MyDevices extends Component {

        ... rest class ...

      render() {
        return(
         <>
          { this.state.house.map(house => <DeviveCard code={house.dwelling_code} /> }
         </>
       ) }
 }
```

---

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I have received an error whilst doing this: ```Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions```. I don't suppose you know how to solve this?

Comment: This error most of the time related to typo issues, misNaming or something like that, please add more of your code for us have the option of help you

Comment: I have just realised, I have forgotten the return statement inside the map function. It works perfectly now, thank you!